# Display urls in the reference section

Tags: bibliographies, urls

I want to know how I can display a url to a site as reference in LaTeX. I need to have them at the end so that I can cite them from the other pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

By reference do you mean citations as in bibliography?

If that is so, you can do it this way.

*In the .tex file*

```
\usepackage{url}


\cite{CADIZ}
```

*In the .bib file*

```
@MISC{CADIZ,
 howpublished ="\url{http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/hise/cadiz/home.html}"
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

To have a URL link just use the [hyperref](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package and `\href{<url>}{<text>}`. For example, the MWE below yields:

[image: screen shot of compiled code: hyperlink to google.com]

and upon mouse click a browser window will be opened to the specified site.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
    \href{http://www.google.com}{Google}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to easily list all the `href` usages at the end of the file, so that the document can also be used when being printed?

Comment: @aexl: Don't think that capavility is built into `hyperref` package, but am sure that that could be done. I suggest you post a new question.